# How or Where to Catch HTML Input Data Submitted via HTML Form in Hapi 18?

Tags: forms, post, input, httprequest, hapi.js

I have this form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email">
    <input type="password">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

to submit input data to my hapi.js server.

At first, I tried to log `request.payload`; but it returned zero object `{}`.

I can catch this, when submitted via `jQuery $.post('url', { payload })`, by `request.payload`.

But, this time I don't use Ajax; just formal html `<form method="POST">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add name attributes to your input elements in order to access their values on your server. Otherwise you cannot distinguish your values on from another.

Try this.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="status">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```